# How can I evade build fails in Hudson when there is no code change?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I am using Hudson to build from Git in my continuous integration system. Everything works fine except that when I start another build without any code change in Git. Then the build just crashes and burns with exceptions. How can I let the Hudson know that if there is no change in the Git side, just rebuild the old code?

Here comes the exception:

```
ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
ERROR: Could not fetch from any repository
FATAL: Could not fetch from any repository
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not fetch from any repository
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:759)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:718)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:756)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:738)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:718)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1171)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:415)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1362)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:405)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
```

Comment: Hudson should do this already, unless you've misconfigured it. What error are you getting?

Comment: Can you give us a clue as to what the exceptions are ?

Comment: Thanks guys, I am re-producing it.

Comment: The exception is updated to the post. Thanks guys.

Comment: How can Hudson know that there are no code changes in your Git repository when it can't connect to your Git origin?  That seems to be what the stacktrace is saying...

Comment: I see. Let me take a look. Thanks for the response.

Comment: However, if so, how can Hudson get info when there is code change? This is very weird.

Comment: This was never answered so I will say that, if you configure the Hudson job properly to where it can 'talk' to the GIT repository, and enable polling, the job itself (prior to even being run) automatically polls GIT in the background, asking GIT if there are outstanding changes since the last build. If changes are detected, Hudson magically schedules a new build, the latest code ends up being checked out, and away it goes.